# dataLoaded state only changed after page reloaded

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm doing an API call to get some data. then I keep a `useState` called `dataLoaded`. on a successful API call I make the `dataLoaded=true`. but to see it changed I have to reload the page.
following is my code.

```
const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() =>{
        const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/movie/`+ path.eventId + `/venue/`+ path.venue +`/showtime`;
        const requestOptions = (token) => {
          return ({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': '4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
          })
        };
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions());
            const json =  await response.json();
            // console.log(json);
            // console.log(json.data.venueDateShowtime)
            setShowTimes(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].showtimes[0]);
            console.log(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].date)
            setShowdate(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].date);
            setDataLoaded(true);
            console.log(dataLoaded)
            console.log(showTimes.showtimeId)
            console.log(showdate)
            if(dataLoaded){
                getSeatsArrangement();
            }
            console.log('jjjj')
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log("error",error);
          }
        };
        fetchData();

      },[]);

      const getSeatsArrangement = async () => {
        const requestOptions = (token) => {
            return ({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': '4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
            })
          };
        console.log(showTimes.showtimeId)
        console.log(showdate)
        try{
            const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/seat?venueId=` + path.venue + `&movieId=`+ path.eventId +`&showtimeId=1011&movieDate=2022-10-11`;
            const response = await fetch(url,requestOptions());
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json)
            setReservedSeats(json.data.reservedSeats.reservedSeat)
            setNonReservedSeats(json.data.reservedSeats.nonReservedSeats)
            console.log(reservedSeats)
            console.log(nonReservedSeats)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("error",error);
        }
    }
```

*Console logs when page loads*

[image: logs]

Comment: What is the aim of the code? `fetchData ` is performed once after page loading (because of using `,[]` at the end of `useeffect`. And a remark: If you log your state right after setting it, the previous value will be shown! you should define another `useeffect` with your state as dependency (for each state) and log your state in there.

Comment: can you please suggest this as an answer?

Comment: Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

What is the aim of the code? `fetchData` is performed once after page loading (because of using `,[]` at the end of `useeffect`.

And a remark: If you log your state right after setting it, the previous value will be shown! you should define another `useeffect` with your state as dependency (for each state) and log your state in there.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dataLoaded)
    if(dataLoaded){
        getSeatsArrangement();
    }
    console.log('jjjj')
}, [dataLoaded]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(showTimes.showtimeId)
}, [showTimes]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(showdate)  
}, [showdate]);

useEffect(() =>{
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/movie/`+ path.eventId + `/venue/`+ path.venue +`/showtime`;
    const requestOptions = (token) => {
      return ({
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': '4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
      })
    };
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions());
        const json =  await response.json();
        // console.log(json);
        // console.log(json.data.venueDateShowtime)
        setShowTimes(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].showtimes[0]);
        console.log(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].date)
        setShowdate(json.data.dateShowtimes[0].date);
        setDataLoaded(true);

      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log("error",error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();

  },[]);
```